# How to draw a baseball in Pixelmator?

Tags: pixelmator

I've changed background color to blue, and put a circle on it. I also changed the color of the inner part of the circle to white. Now I want to depict seams on it... how can I draw the seams?

I can accept that the seam is just the curved line - i.e. I don't need the dashed line or the "real" seam, which is a collection of small horizontal lines, since I don't like the idea of spending another 10 or even 20 hours just learning about how to draw a "real" seam. Here's the image that I intended to depict, though since I don't know how to depict it in a computational way, I just overlaid a circle on the original circle and erased the redundant part with an eraser by hand, and finally duplicated it and transposed the duplicated line. But since the hand-written curve is quite awful, I want to make the curve look more fluent.

[image]

[Update]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make the lines in 5 seconds then click on PenTool and on the artboard click once at the upper point - look at the picture below, press Shift and move mouse down (or up if you started at lower border of a ball), then - when you at lower border of a ball click (and don't leave the button) and start dragging the directional line in a direction which will give you a nice arcuate line. Once you've done with arc leave the mouse button and click Escape. Finally, choose the desired width of the stroke and duplicate+mirror the line.

[image: first]

You've done:

[image: illustration]

Comment: Hmmm... It looks like this works only sometimes and doesn't always; It instead makes me depict the awkward arc - check out my updated post on the two black lines.

Comment: Ok, you dont need create a second arc - you copy and paste the first one and then Flip It Horizontally

Comment: Another way is to just a straight line (click first point, click second point) then 'grab' the middle of the line and drag it out to make the curve.