# How do I create a bezier curve in illustrator with known values

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cinema4d, bezier-curve

I want to create a Bézier curve in Illustrator so I can import it into Cinema 4D. Now my problem is, I have got a Bézier curve with just the coordinates of my points and I want to draw this in Illustrator. How do I do that?

Coordinates are:
(5,0)
(3,0.5)
(0,1)
(-2,1)
(-3.5,1)
(-5,0.5)
(-5,0)

Comment: I don't think you can. Illustrator isn't geared towards CAD or plotting.

Comment: @Scott know an alternative then?

Comment: SVG files can be viewed in text editors and manipulated that way... so maybe there's an answer there.

Comment: @BrianC sure. For the martjin id suggest reading: http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/37998/how-to-create-a-vector-curve-programmatically/38010#38010 i am currently on the summer cottage about 150 km from the closest computer that i have access to with illustrator. This answer should provide enough info to do this.

Comment: @joojaa Thanks for the answer! That's exactly what I was looking for.